# Separate CLI commands over multiple Python files

Tags: python, python-click

I'm trying to package a command line interface, developed with the Click library. To experiment, I made another CLI test app with commands that do nothing to test things out.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
Grouptest
> scripts
  > __init__.py
  > amogus.py
  > maintest.py
> main.py
> utils.py
> Grouptest.egg-info
> setup.py
```

How would I seperate Click commands into seperate scripts and not have to make 2 commands?

As in, if my common command prefix was going to be `testcli1`, I want to be able to call commands in maintest with `testcli1 maintest`, and commands in `amogus.py` with `testcli1 amongus`.

I tried making `@click.group` decos in `maintest.py`, and then in `amogus.py` I imported the needed @click.group deco from `maintest.py`, but when I install with `pip install -e .`, when I call maintest, it doesn't recognize the commands from `amogus.py`.

How do I split up commands over several python files? I really don't want to make an amalgamation file, that would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have four files-

- entrypoint.py (the entrypoint for your script)
- main.py (create the group)
- a.py (a command)
- b.py (b command)

---

- in main.py create a click.group
- in command files import that group from main, and decorate your commands
- in entrypoint, import all the other files and execute your group.

The ORDER of imports in your entrypoint matters! If a or b aren't imported, their commands just won't be registered.

But those files don't work if they are imported before the group is created.

You have the option of doing some magic in the entrypoint file (search for all files and import them), but I usually just do that manually.

Comment: Would I insert the import statements inside the click.group?

Comment: I usually use a separate file (entrypoint.py) to make it work. You COULD build the group and THEN import the child files as well, but I don't like the way that looks. (if you import them at the top of group.py, you'll get circular import errors)

Comment: Okay, you mentioned "doing some magic in the entrypoint file by searching for all files and importing them". Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: magic was extreme. Something like `for path in Path(__file__).parent.iterdir(): importlib.import_module(str(path)`